# Unity: 2D Collision Detection Using Tags

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, collision

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Bullet")
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
        Debug.Log("hit");
    }
}
```

This is my code, I appreciate that there is a lot of other sources out there however I have looked on the internet and just cannot understand where im going wrong. I know its probably something so small. I'm attempting to get on collision detect destroy "this" game object using the tag. The Bullet prefab has the Bullet tag and is spelt exactly the same, both gameObjects have both a rigidbody and a 2D box collider.

Any help will be great.

Comment: You may want to explain more precisely **what happens** vs **what you want to happen** and what object uses this code.

Comment: Right now I'm not even sure is this code executed on bullets or destructible objects. The same goes with who is tagged.

Comment: Nothing actually happen, the script is on an enemy AI sprite, I want it so when the bullet collides the current game object (enemy AI sprite) is destroyed. No other object uses this code other that the prefab for the enemy AI sprite prefab. And no they have separate tags, the enemy AI sprite is tagged enemyship and the bullet is tagged bullet.

Comment: Try printing out name + tag of this gameObject to see what it's colliding with instead

Comment: In general rather use [`if(collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Bullet"))`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.CompareTag.html) just to rule out any spelling mistakes since instead of failing silently it directly throws an error if given tag name is spelled wrong/doesn't exist. (It's also slightly faster then string comparison ;) ) Also, is one of both maybe a `isTrigger`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

things to check:

- Rigibody2D are simulated (in inspector Rigidbody2D simulated check is true)
- none of the colliders are set to isTrigger
- because this is 2d so make sure both sprites are on the same layer order or z-order
- try debugging and check which object is bullet hitting

(and i assume you have Rigidbody2D not Rogidbody like you mentioned in your question)

(if all of these are checked then just for testing try to decrease the speed of bullet, if bullet is going too fast then try changing “Collision Detection” to continues)

most imported thing “debug”
and debug before destroying not after

Comment: Thanks! I ended up restarting the project and checking the new project against the things you have mentioned and it seem to work, maybe it was just that project, or something I was missing, thanks tho :)

Answer (score 1):

Better practive is to use `CompareTag` instead:

```
private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision other) {
    if(other.gameObject.CompareTag("Ground")) {
        isJumping = false;
    }
}
```